# Can we defined a metric so that the non-constant cauchy sequence do not exists, then the space is complete vacuiously

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, complete-spaces

I know that not all metrics are induced by norm, only those metrics satisfy the homogeneity and translation invariant.

**1**. Now, Can a normed space equipped with metric not be induced by the norm?

**2**. If it can, consider this metric if $x\neq y$ $$d(x,y):=\max \{\lVert x-y\rVert_{2},1 \}$$ $$d(x,y):=0\quad x=y$$ with the normed space, my motivation of this metric is bounded below to make sure that there can not have a Cauchy sequence in the space (except for the trivial constant sequence). In such case, is the space vacuously complete by no non-constant Cauchy sequence exists, so that every Cauchy sequence convergence in the space?

Please help me out with these two questions

Comment: Yes, the space is complete immediately. Also, note that every set is open in that metric (so as far as topology goes, you might as well have taken the discrete metric to start with).

Comment: If $(X,\|.\|)$ is any nls then $d(x,y)=\frac {\|x-y\|}{1+\|x-y\|}$ defines a metric which is not given by a norm but it has the same topology as the given norm.